# Aweber PHP API: Pass meta_web_form_id when creating new subscriber

Tags: php, aweber

Need help with Aweber PHP API.
https://labs.aweber.com/docs/reference/1.0#subscribers as you can see I can't pass meta_web_form_id into CREATE function, so how can I track which form was submited?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using Aweber forms tho, you're using the API? In order to track where the subscriber is coming from you can use the **ad_tracking** field.

> You could assign each subscriber that comes through your web form the ad tracking category "web_form", those that come through newsletters the category "newsletter", and those that come through classified ads the category "classified".
>
> https://help.aweber.com/entries/21694288-what-is-ad-tracking

Comment: I want to track displays and submissions on Web Forms page. Use split test and e.t.c.